# matlab: convert char array into string

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I implemented a bash script in matlab, which returns a char array with all the outputs (echo). Now I would like to use the data stored in the array, to open a file. Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert the array into a string.
The following code works:

```
[status, output] = system('./script.sh', '-echo');
filename = [ output(1) output(2) output(3) output(4) output(5) output (6) ];
```

But it is not very convenient and doesn't allow different lengths of the filename.
Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: does filename = output(:) help? Otherwise can you post the result if you type output in the command line?

Comment: filename = output(1:end-1) solved it...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, character arrays *are* strings; there's no need to convert them.

```
filename = output
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Okay, my fault...the array had an empty cell (probably a command) at the end, so Matlab couldn't open the file. filename = output(1:end-1) solved it. Thanks!